# Valid edit to my post was rejected. How to bring it back?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

Some anonymous guy edited my answer recently.
Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/897372

Five users reviewed this edit and three of them rejected it as invalid.
I think that the correction is **absolutely valid** (missing function argument was added).

What is the correct way of bringing this edit back and accepting it?

Comment: Copy and paste. There's no way you can accept it. The original editor is anonymous so you can't ask them to re-submit.

Comment: Reviewers tend to reject most any substantial code edits (of which this was one).  I probably would have rejected it as well.  Normally I would look for a comment asking you to change this and given you an opportunity to fix it first.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks. Adding a comment looks like a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: @maxtaldykin in this specific case, a comment would not have worked since a new or anonymous user can't post comments, but in general, I tend to error on the side of caution when approving/rejecting edits to code in answers, and I think most reviewers do the same.  For questions I almost automatically reject anything that wasn't discussed in comments as changes to code change the question and could invalidate answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "bring it back" if it was rejected. You'll have to copy/paste his edit onto your answer, and edit it yourself.

You as the post owner, can approve/reject edits with a single vote. Use that power next time.