# How should I deal with a good suggested edit to my answer which was incorrectly rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[The edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2653421) was in source code due to an API that changed. It's actually an awesome edit because I would have never have noticed the error in an old answer.

I'm not sure why the edit was rejected, by people who don't have knowledge of the API in question, it seems.

Should I just make the edit myself, or get the user to re-suggest it?

Comment: just make the edit.

Comment: @Bart Are there attribution issues with simply making the edit?  A suggesting user is contributing content based on certain expectations of attribution (e.g., being listed in the edit history) that are broken if the owner simply makes the edit.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If it's something truly substantial you could always give credit. But for something this small (which could have been a comment as well) I would simply not bother. Many of my edits are not made with an expectation of attribution, but a simple desire to see the content improved.

Comment: @Bart True, but if the suggester comes back later, sees their content with no attribution, it seems like they could legitimately flag as plagiarism (citing the "suggested edit rejected" page).  This is why I've just upvoted the [Allow the owner of a post to approve a suggested edit even if it was rejected by reviewers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157852/225437) feature request.  A simple "approve anyway" button for the post owner would keep the correct attribution around.

Comment: Nah, that's taking the whole plagiarism idea way too far. And if the original author truly has a problem with that happening, he could simply create his own answer to begin with.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thank you for the"technique" you used to further refine my suggested edit this time (as compared to the previous one that you must remember). This is what I perceive as collaboration at work. "My" preference of phrasing was rather my prior version, but the way you reworked it is an acceptable alternative for me. My goal was to make this "awesome" question make more shine like it originally was (sorry Justin), and that goal I achieved now. "Now" I consider you as a new SE-friend (before I had my doubts, sorry).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: I am well aware of that “technique” and used it before (e.g., [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37932)). As for that previous edit: I explained to you why I rejected it and I would do so again. If you think that was inappropriate, you can start a discussion about it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : thx for the feedback, and clarification of your viewpoint. For me there is no real need to open a discussion on that specific topic as you suggested, unless "you" would want to do so. To be honest I have "other" items that I'd rather would want to get feedback about from  you (friend, remember!), like can you help me understand the final reject reason of this recent one (from Martijn ...): http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38039 I don't want to appeal the verdict, I just don't understand the reason. Or just use my suggested edit and fix what's broken in it.

Comment: If you want to do so, that "technique" from above obviously is not going to work in this case, so you do whatever fits to reach the goal: an enhanced version as compared to what it looks like now, use any of my rejected edit if you want to do so. Credits, etc do not apply in this specific case of course.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We sprang into action upon observing this problem, and less than 4 years later [a solution is in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028) - post authors can now override the decision on suggested edits, accepting or rejecting edits even if the reviewers previously decided on something else.

Comment: It'd totally make sense to have that feature. I had several edits on my posts rejected, but all were made by a user I completely trust in editing my posts, even if those are more than minor changes or involve source code.

Comment: @slhck You *trust* people with < 2k reputation?! The shock! The horror!

Comment: Thanks @Shog9, will do. That feature is exactly what I want as well.

Comment: As an Answer of mine was [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3780441) by a user and then *incorrectly* rejected by three other users, I would certainly welcome some way to override their decision. At the very least this new user got slapped down for making a perfectly valid change to my Answer.