# A good edit to my answer was incorrectly rejected

Tags: support, review, rejected-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3007304) to my answer was nice and added example code. It improved the answer. Somehow four reviewers have rejected it! I have since manually added the code to the answer, but the reviews were IMHO ridiculous.

Could the moderators remove any black marks the editor (also asker of the question) got for this incorrectly rejected edit?

Comment: Alas code suggested edits are almost always rejected as the reviewers can't know its what you intended. Theres a feature request for this though; [allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by)

Comment: Well, I'm the author of the answer, I can always edit it back as I'm notified about those edits, right?

Comment: If a reviewer lacks subject matter knowledge to know whether the code is relevant to the question and the answer, they should just skip it! I often skip reviews where I don't know enough to be sure.

Comment: This still makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Just for a bit of information the author of the edit was the OP that asked the question.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: which was not visible during the review.

Comment: @user7116 I know, I just find that it is important to this discussion. Since I did not find the information in the question, I add it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of answers is for there to be several of them which are voted upon, by interjecting another answer into yours (even if it is better) the voting system is being subverted. If the editor has a (in their mind) better answer they should post it separately and let the voters decide. Even if it I am a subject level expert it is not for me to decide that this new answer from a completely new person deserves the existing votes.

As it is impossible to say if the OP of the answer intended the additional code to be in their answer it is always rejected. There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by) to allow retrospective approval that you may wish to support.

Comment: It wasn't "another" answer, it was merely code added to illustrate the prose in my answer. It was as if the answer was a wiki, but I didn't mark it as such yet.

Comment: @kuba had you marked it as a wiki there would be no problem,  as you hadn't the reviewers defended your rights to (limited) creative control of your question

Comment: OK, we definitely need a way to manually approve rejected edits to our own answers, then. I've upvoted the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by).

Comment: @KubaOber And found me arguing almost the opposite way in an answer to that question. I'm weird like that

Comment: @KubaOber: you don't have to mark your answer as a wiki to allow others to edit it. The edit button is clearly there for all types of answers. The OP simply ran afoul of using code in an edit, which is a huge faux pas. The correct approach is to add their edit back if it works for you (99 of 100 code edits do not apply, hence the byzantine rejection).

Comment: @user7116 However the *rules* of editing are different between a community wiki and a normal post

Comment: @RichardTingle: you cannot materially change a CW post. The rules really are not that different.

Comment: @user7116: Is *adding relevant code* a material change to a post? To me it's an incremental improvement!

Comment: @user7116 From the [FAQ on community wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) "They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users". and "continually evolving source of good information" Sounds like different rules to me

Comment: @RichardTingle: a code only answer is not an answer.